# flutter: Failed to load font Roboto at https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Me5WZLCzYlKw.ttf

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, google-fonts, roboto, android-studio-electric-eel

I have updated my Android Studio to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1.

While trying to run my Flutter starter app on Chrome web I got a blank web page with this error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while running my flutter project. I used 'flutter run -d chrome' to run it and the issue disappeared.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downloading and installing the roboto font separately.

First download the ttf file through the browser, and then install it to your system, the error log will disappear when you run the program again.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by including `Roboto` font family locally in my project.

```yaml
  fonts:
    - family: SomeFont
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/SomeFont/SF-Regular.ttf
    - family: Roboto # Here
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf
```

#### Before include

[image]

#### After include Roboto Font family

[image]

Also you can use `Roboto` as fallback font family:

```dart
ThemeData(
      fontFamilyFallback: const ["Roboto"],
);
```